# BasicDBObject parse throwing invalid json number

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am using this code, to create an aggregation query but I am getting a `JsonParseException : invalid json number`

```
Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("if",  BasicDBObject.parse("{'$gte':[{'$subtract':
[{'$ifNull':['$acceptedDate', " + new Date() + "]},'$lastVisit']},1296000000]}}"));
```

Is there perhaps a different way to map this query?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BasicDBObject parse accepts the [json extended version](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#data_date). To pass date you have to pass the time in millis from epoch.

Something like

```
BasicDBObject.parse("
 {'$gte':[
   {'$subtract':[
     {'$ifNull':['$acceptedDate', {'$date': " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "}]},
     '$lastVisit'
   ]},
   1296000000
 ]}"
)
```

Comment: hey Veeram, this did not throw errors, thanks a lot. But i do have a question. I made a mistake and my acceptedDate is actually an array like this `"acceptedDate" : [ 
 {"value" : ISODate(a date) }]` and the lastVisit date is a regular field `"lastVisit" : ISODate(a date)`. The thing is that acceptedDate may or may not exist .  :(